# How can I detect elements of GUI using opencv?

Tags: image-processing, edge-detection, opencv

Given a screenshot of an application, is there any way of finding GUI elements of that application using only opencv? (something like in the image)
[image: Desired Outlook image after element detection]

I tried to play with blending the image and other effects from the coherence.py sample in the opencv installation folder. Did not succeed to get a viable result.

Has anyone did this? Do you have any idea what I might try?

Thanks

(I'm new to opencv and image processing so please don't avoid obvious explanations if possible) :)

Comment: This is not in OpenCV, [but have a look at Sikuli.org](http://sikuli.org/) which has exactly the purpose you're looking for

Comment: i know about Sikuli. What i needed was a way to detect the areas of interest without actually taking a screen-shot of them in advance. The answer was the MSER approach with specific initialization. Anyway, thanks for the Sikuli tip.

Comment: If I may ask what were you programming? I got here searching for the same question. My intention is to make elements keyboard-clickable when for applications that don't have keyboard shortcuts defined. Did you worked on something similar?

Comment: No, it was for a small project of UI test automation. It was supposed to "watch" the user interact with the UI and then generate small scripts to replay the actions. I abandoned it at some point due to Sikuli's lack of reliability on long term. I could get screenshots of the elements in UI, but Sikuli did not manage to find all of them in 100% of cases (probably they were too small or too similar to other elements)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OpenCV's [MSER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximally_stable_extremal_regions) extractor ([documented here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/feature_detection.html#mser)) might be helpful — the bounding box of local MSER groups would pretty closely match the green rectangles in your mockup.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like what I'm looking for. I'll give it a try one of these days

Comment: Yap. I did it. I just have to fine tune it now for what I need. Thanks again.